# How to get a number of friends that like particular page in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to build an app that tells user how many of his friends like a particular facebook page. 
Let's say the name of page is Machester United. And I have 20 friends who like that page.

How can I do that? Should I use facebook graphAPI? Are there any other ways>

I am very new to this. Can you give me some key concepts/things that I should look into?

Comment: The OP has another question than the one which is marked as duplicate, respectively all the solutions which are outlines in the "duplicate" are not applicable for his use case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Social Context API might be the right thing for you, if you're mainly interested in the number of friends which like a certain Facebook Page.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.0

Use

```
GET /cocacola?fields=context.fields(friends_who_like)
```

to see which/how many of your friends like the **CocaCola** Page.

The result will look like

```
{
  "context": {
    "friends_who_like": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "123456789", 
          "name": "Firstname Lastname"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "ODQ5MDkwMjQ2", 
          "after": "ODQ5MDkwMjQ2"
        }
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "social_sentence": "4 of your friends like this.", 
        "total_count": 4
      }
    }
  }, 
  "id": "40796308305"
}
```

The `context.summary.total_count` field will contain the number of friends which like the Page.

Try it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola%3Ffields%3Dcontext.fields(friends_who_like)&version=v2.0

Keep in mind that

> In order for a person to be identifiably returned in a context edge, they must have:
>
> - Logged into the app.
> - Granted the user_friends permission.
> - Granted the appropriate content permission in order to see the action. For example, to    appear in the friends_who_like context edge, each friend has to have granted the app the user_likes permission.